# Displaying data from a database using a search query

Tags: php, sql

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <input type="text" name="q"></input><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search"></input>
  </form>
```

form

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])){
$target= $_REQUEST['q'];
$sql = " SELECT *
         FROM TABLE1
         WHERE name
         LIKE '%$target%'";

  $result = $mysqli->query($sql)
  or die($mysqli->error . "<pre>$sql</pre>");
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row["number"] . " " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["hp"] . "<br>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

result.php

Trying to use a search query to display data from the database. When the user submits the form nothing displays on the next page, not even the else. Unsure what's wrong and I'm struggling to find help in other threads. Thanks.

Comment: What would happen if there were no rows in the result?

Comment: Put `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your page to make sure you are getting post variables you expect. (and `print_r($_REQUEST);`)

Comment: $conn is $mysqli, but nowhere is that declared.  Error reporting?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is crashing because you are using two different variables for the mysqli connection.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
/* was $conn */ 
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

// change $conn tp $mysqli
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if (isset($_REQUEST['q'])){
    $target= $_REQUEST['q'];
    $sql = " SELECT *
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE name
     LIKE '%$target%'";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql)
        or die($mysqli->error . "<pre>$sql</pre>");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["number"] . " " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["hp"] . "<br>";
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: Good catch. Is worth mentioning that this script is vulnerable to SQL injection. I suggest the author to look into prepared statements or using PDO.